# Called a jquery after javascript ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this javascript code which returns an ajax request

```
function showUser(str)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("lister").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","popup.php?qq="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I tried to execute a jquery that can't be done , unless ajax request returns , yet it's not working

```
$('#scrollbar2').tinyscrollbar();
```

So how should I execute that last jquery after the ajax load ?

Comment: If you already use jQuery, is there any particular reason for relying on this `XMLHttpRequest` instead of using jQuery's methods for doing AJAX such as `$.ajax`?

Comment: IMO, at your level, there's no point in NOT using jQuery's ajax methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it inside the callback after you set `lister`’s `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("lister").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
$('#scrollbar2').tinyscrollbar();
```

But since you have jQuery, why not use its Ajax functionality?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "popup.php",
    data: { qq: str },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response) {
        $('#lister').html(response);
        $('#scrollbar2').tinyscrollbar();
    }
});
```

Comment: I should put that code inside the the function showUser(str) ??

Answer (score 0):

Add the jQuery call inside your `onreadystatechange` callback.  The reason for this is that ajax completes *asynchronously* (as per its name).  Think of it like this:

```
onAjaxComplete = function () {
    // this will run second
}
// this will run first
```

All work that depends on the result of the ajax call must be in the callback.

Additionally, since you are using jQuery anyway you might as well use their ajax API which is a lot simpler.

```
function showUser(str) {
    $.get("popup.php", "qq=" + str).done(function (responseText) {
        $("#lister").html(responseText);
        $("#scrollbar2").tinyscrollbar();
    });
}
```

Comment: It didn't work !!! The $("#scrollbar2").tinyscrollbar(); isn't doing anything ! Also the ajax request is not acquired